# Sum Mutable Map values inside a list of objects kotlin

Tags: kotlin, hashmap

I have a data class in Kotlin like this:

```
data class Activity(
    var id: String? = "",
    var prize: MutableMap<String?, Int?>? = null
)
```

And a list of this object:

```
var myList = listOf(Activity("A", prize={day_5=70, day_4=70}), 
                    Activity("B", prize={day_5=40, day_4=80}))
```

The desired result is:

```
Activity("A", prize={total=140}), 
Activity("B", prize={total=120})
```

So basically I want to sum the values of the prize map inside of each object.

I think that has something to do with transformation but I'm new to Kotlin and I couldn't find any resources over the internet, or maybe they were to complicated.

Comment: You mean you want to clear the map and put a new entry in it that is the sun of all the previous entries? This seems like an XY problem, and also like you’re trying to work with Kotlin as if it’s not a strongly typed language.

Comment: @Tenfour04 or create another list without modifying the existing one, the problem is that I don't know how to sum the values inside a map. That's it

Comment: If the values were Int instead of Int?, all you would need to  get the sum: `prize.values.sum()` If you really need the values to be nullable like that, `prize.values.filterNotNull().sum()` But there are several code smells. Everything in your code is mutable and nullable in every possible way. And it seems like you’re using a Map to avoid strongly typed properties.

Comment: @Tenfour04, thank you. I changed to Int as you said and I can sum the values. The process of learning is long and difficult. Thanks again

Comment: @Tenfour04 so I created another object named `Stats` that has just an Id as String and a Prize as Int and then I followed your instruction and did like this: `val transformed: MutableList<Stats> = result.map { Stats(it.id, it.prize?.values?.sum()) }.toMutableList()`. In this way I get what I want. TY man

Answer (score 0):

This algorithm is easy, just iterating through all the maps and replace elements with the sum:

```kotlin
val myList = listOf(
    Activity("A", hashMapOf("day_5" to 70, "day_4" to 70)),
    Activity("B", hashMapOf("day_5" to 40, "day_4" to 80)),
)

for (i in myList) {
    val total = i.prize.values.sum()
    i.prize.clear()
    i.prize["total"] = total
}
```